# SSRS sum values by different group and merge cells

Tags: reporting-services

[image: DataSet]

[image: Question]
I got a sum Table 1 from a dataset, grouped by a parent Group 1 and a child group 2.For C, it sums values for different Sites.

The table I really want is to merge the SumValue under one column and re-name the group, e.g., C1 & C2 instead of Site-C1 & Site-C2.

I have tried to rename the Group 2 from Site_C1 and Site_C2 to C1 and C2, but it still splits to different columns:

[image: not work]

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: You could try to solve this by adding a column group. I can't really tell what to group on or even what you're grouping on now without knowing your actual dataset layout. What columns does your dataset have?

Comment: @Oceans Thank you, I've added the DS example. How to add a column group?

Comment: I still don't get how your dataset is formed. Why does each record have a column based on another Id? Like in your example, site with id 10 has a column C for id 11 and 12... why or how? The solution posted by user2900970 was the first thing that came to my mind as well.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion :)  "site with id 10 has a column C for id 11 and 12" - 10-C, 11-C and 12-C are Group 2 names, so for Site 10, values are only available for 10-C, no values for 11-C and 12-C. @Oceans

Comment: You confuse me because you said you added the DS example, yet you still have groups in it? How does your DS look like without the groupings, what are the columns?

Comment: You must have a serious design flaw. So many useless columns. You now want them to be merged together, so why did you separate them in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is similar to a question you posted before. As I said in that moment you can use an expression to conditionally set the grouping settings in your matrix. Add a matrix and add the `Group 1` to Column Groups

[image]

In the `Group properties` / `Group on` put this expression:

```
=IIF(
Fields!Group.Value="C",
RIGHT(Fields!Subgroup2.Value,2),
Fields!Group.Value
)
```

> Note `Subgroup2` is `Group 2` in your case.

Put the same expression on the header (the selected cell in the screenshot). It will preview the following matrix:

[image]

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: HaHa thanks. I was thinking if you will see this question and help me out on this one. I made the subgroup2 names simpler for this example, they are actually 'SiteName'&'DeptNames'. Both the SiteName and DeptNames have various lengths. I can't do RIGHT(Fields!Subgroup2.Value,2) to get a tidy and neat new Group, but following your logic, I think I can work something out. Thank you very much again, will let you know :)

Comment: if they are separated by `-` as your example, you can use this: `=RIGHT(Fields!Subgroup2.Value,
LEN(Fields!Subgroup2.Value)-InStr(Fields!Subgroup2.Value,"-")
)` . Otherwise try finding a pattern to separate Site and Dept. Hope it helps.

Comment: Tested, the Logic still works great. Thank you for the above, unfortunately there are no special separator between them. I think the easiest way I could try is to change the name structure to something similar in my example. Many thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I would add one ore more [calculated field](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239322.aspx) to the dataset. There you can add the values of the relevant columns like this:

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!C10.Value), 0,Fields!C10.Value) 
+ IIF(IsNothing(Fields!C11.Value), 0,Fields!C11.Value) 
+ IIF(IsNothing(Fields!C11.Value), 0,Fields!C12.Value)
```

In your table, don't bind a column to C10, C11.. but bind it to the calculated field.

Comment: Thank you very much for this method, @user2900970. But I have many sites, it will be unrealistic to add all the sites to DS calculated field. Is there anyway around? E.g. Dataset coding? Thanks.